# Create a 1D array of all 2D combinations [11,12,13,...32,33] from a 1D array [1,2,3]

Tags: javascript, d3.js

From a 1D array [1,2,3], create a 1D array of all 2D combinations 11,12,13,...32,33.  I can do it, it's just a bit ugly.  Is there a neater way to write it?

```js
const intArr = [1,2,3];

const data = intArr.map(v1 => 
    intArr.map(v2 => v1 + ',' + v2)
).flat();

d3.select('ul')
    .selectAll('li')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('li')
    .text(d => d)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: Why are you using d3 to... perform DOM manipulation?

Comment: Its opinion based question. I would use nested loop and `document.createElement`

Comment: I use d3 because the page is already using d3 for other things.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.map(n => arr.map(m => '' + n + m)).flat()
```

is a completely valid way of creating a [cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12303989/7126740) in Javascript. You can also do

```
arr.flatMap(n => arr.map(m => '' + n + m))
```